# How do I define whether a parameter is required or not using Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm creating an Axios request function where I have a looot of parameters for the body request. Most are required, but some are not. What's the best way to handle this?

```
createAccount(username, first_name, last_name, email, language, client_name, client_email, website_url, street, city, code, country, language, lead_source, date_picker) {
        return this.axiosInstance.post('/brands/image', {
            username: username,
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            email: email,
            language: language,
            client_name: client_name,
            client_email: client_email,
            website: website,
            street: street,
            city: city,
            code: code,
            country: country,
            lead_source: lead_source, // non-required
            date_picker: date_picker, // // non-required


        })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error: ", error)
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches you can take:

- Read the API documentation of the web service you are making requests to (which could be designed for humans or might be a machine readable JSON schema or similar)
- Trial and error

There's no way for the client to know what the server cares about.